# C# Reload file after resume and navigation back

Tags: c#, windows-phone, reload, windows-phone-silverlight

As a topic. How to reload file MainPage.xaml for example in windows phone application(8.1) every time, when application is resumed or navigate back.

I using silverlight project.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with `Response.Redirect()` method at the server side or use `Form.Submit` at Client side..

For more examples then you can refer to the following 
[link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1161549.aspx).

Comment: I spoke a little bad. I mean reload MainPage.xaml file, for example.

Comment: when does it need to be reloaded

Comment: every time when the application is resumed or the user presses the back button.
as the key back I would have advised, I don't know hot to detect that the application is resumed after working in the background.